# Custom Google Maps not showing on mobile and tablets

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, google-maps-api-3, device

I run into something strange, my custom Google maps is not visible on mobile phones or tablets. But on the desktop it works fine. I can not put my finger on the problem.

My html is as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="maps-canvas"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

And my custom JS:

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
    if ($('#maps-canvas').length) {
        CustomGoogleMaps();
    }
});

function CustomGoogleMaps() {
    // Creating a LatLng object containing the coordinate for the center of the map
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.145022, 5.422421);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps-canvas'), {
        //options
        zoom: 18, // This number can be set to define the initial zoom level of the map
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, // This value can be set to define the map type ROADMAP/SATELLITE/HYBRID/TERRAIN

        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
        },

        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        streetViewControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
        }
    });

    // Detect the resize event and keep marker in center when on resize
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function () {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
    });

    // Define Marker properties
    var imagePath = "http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/sailboat-tourism.png";
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imagePath,
        // This marker is 75 pixels wide by 101 pixels tall.
        new google.maps.Size(75, 101),
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 18,101.
        new google.maps.Point(18, 101)
    );

    // Add Marker
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.145022, 5.422421),
        map: map,
        icon: image, // This path is the custom pin to be shown. Remove this line and the proceeding comma to use default pin
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, // Animate drop effect of the marker
        position: latlng // The position should be the latlng coordinates
    });

    // Add listener for a click on the pin
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function () {
        infowindow1.open(map, marker1);
    });

    // Add information window
    //change address details here
    var contentString = '<div class="map-info-box">'
    + '<div class="map-head">'
    + '<h3>Company Title</h3></div>'
    + '<p class="map-address">My Address</p>';

    var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,
    });

    // Create information window
    function createInfo(title, content) {
        return '<div class="maps-info-window"><strong>' + title + '</strong><br />' + content + '</div>';
    }
}
```

[See also my working jsfiddle](http://#).

Hope someone can help me on the right path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simpler alternative to my above solution:

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
    // Remove this next block of code, or comment out, because I think it is calling your function before it is available
    //if ($('#maps-canvas').length) {
        //CustomGoogleMaps();
    //}
});
```

Instead, wherever you are enqueueing your script, add that function as a callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=CustomGoogleMaps"></script>
```

If this works, we at least know that it was a timing issue.

Answer (score 0):

How are you enqueuing your Google maps API script? It could  be a timing issue. It is possible that it is loading much quicker on desktop, and therefore it is always available when your code tries to call:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.145022, 5.422421);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps-canvas') .....
```

It is possible that the library is loading slower on mobile, and therefore the script isn't ready by the time you are trying to call the google.maps functions, which causes an error, and therefore preventing your map from loading.

There are ways to go about this to ensure your library is loaded before you attempt to call its functions. Here is a method I used recently:

```
CustomGoogleMaps = (function(){
    var googleMapsLoaded = $.Deferred(); 

    var init = function(){
        var self = this; 
        googleMapsLoaded.done( function(){
            self.initializeMap(); 
        }); 
    }

    var initializeMap = function(){
        // initialize your map here
        var map = new google.maps.Map("yourMapContainer") // etc.... 
    }

    // rest of your google maps stuff here 

    return {
        googleMapsLoaded : googleMapsLoaded,
        init : init, 
        initializeMap : initializeMap
    }
})();
```

Then, where you are enqueueing your script, you can actually pass a callback as a parameter, and that function will be run after the google maps library is available, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=CustomGoogleMaps.googleMapsLoaded.resolve"></script>
```

And where ever you are trying to initialize your map:

```
CustomGoogleMaps.Init()
```

Here is how this works:

Your JS runs the CustomGoogleMaps.Init() function. If the GoogleMapsLoaded promise has already been resolved (meaning the library is ready), your initializeMap() function will go ahead and run immediately. If NOT, it will WAIT for that promise to be resolved. If it is waiting for it to be resolved, once your google maps script loads, it will run the

```
CustomGoogleMaps.googleMapsLoaded().resolve()
```

which will resolve the promise, and therefore the initializeMap() function (which is currently waiting on the promise to resolve), will run, and you can kick off your map initialization.

**EDIT:**

My suggestion requires some relatively significant structural changes to your code. A quicker, simpler solution would be to just pass your CustomGoogleMaps function as a callback, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=CustomGoogleMaps"></script>
```

Comment: Although, my example is following the Revealing Module Pattern. I guess a much simpler approach for your purposes, would be to just pass your CustomGoogleMaps function as a callback to the google maps script.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort but it's still not working. Is it possible that you change my fiddle?